# How can i use Kint Debugger in symfony controller

Tags: php, debugging, symfony, xdebug

I am trying to use this

https://github.com/barelon/CgKintBundle
https://github.com/raveren/kint

for debugging

Now i am able to see debugging in TWIG templates but i am not sure how to use

https://github.com/raveren/kint#installation-and-usage

in symfony php clases.

```
require '/kint/Kint.class.php';

########## DUMP VARIABLE ###########################
Kint::dump($GLOBALS, $_SERVER); // any number of parameters
// or simply use d() as a shorthand:
d($_SERVER);
```

do i need to add this code in controller of symfony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kint already comes with a `autoload` section in it's [composer.json](https://github.com/raveren/kint/blob/master/composer.json#L22) and the [Kint class](https://github.com/raveren/kint/blob/master/Kint.class.php#L15) itself doesn't have a namespace.

`composer` will take care of the autoloading for you which means the `require` statement isn't necessary.

You can use this *"debugging tool"* in **any** class (controller,entity, ...) like this:

```
\Kint::dump($someVariable);
```

It's just a prettyfied version of `var_dump()`.

I suggest you take a look at [raulfraile/LadyBugBundle](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle) which uses [ladybug](https://github.com/raulfraile/Ladybug) instead of `Kint` 
... but can highlight symfony/doctrine classes with funky symbols aswell.

If you want *real* debugging capabilities ... install [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: thanks ladybug was execellent, i installed xdebug as mentioned but could not find how to use it

Comment: I tried using ladybug , so far i am only able to use `labybug_dump` which works ok , all other functions like `ladybug_dump_return` are not working. its says function not found in namespace

Comment: Please open another question for your current issue. I will try to help if i can. :)

Comment: I have added new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980060/few-function-of-ladybug-debugger-not-working-in-symfony2-php-app

Comment: Hey, author of Kint here, could you please elaborate, what does `symfony/doctrine classes with funky symbols` mean? I'd like to implement that too :)

Comment: I used ladybug but Kint is just .... better : variable name, no nested limitations, timestamp displayed as a date/time ...