# Few function of ladybug debugger not working in symfony2 php app

Tags: php, debugging, symfony

I am using this

https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle

They have three functions

```
ld($var1[, $var2[, ...]]): shortcut for ladybug_dump

ldd($var1[, $var2[, ...]]): shortcut for ladybug_dump_die

ldr($format, $var1[, $var2[, ...]]): shortcut for ladybug_return
```

First two are working but for third it says undefined function

Also i tried this to dump json then i also get error

`ld(json_decode($jsonContent, true));`

and i get this

> UndefinedFunctionException: Attempted to call function "bccomp" from
>   namespace "Ladybug\Type" in
>   /var/www/html/site/Symfony/vendor/raulfraile/ladybug/src/Ladybug/Type/FloatType.php
>   line 115

Answer (score 2):

The [bccomp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php) function needs the php [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/bc.requirements.php) extension.

> These functions are only available if PHP was configured with
>   **--enable-bcmath** .
>
> The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension

Check `php -i | grep -i bcmath` ...

There should be a line ...

```
BCMath support => enabled
```

... if the extension is enabled. Otherwise you'll probably need to recompile php with `--enable-bcmath`.

Comment: is there any other way to fix that without recompiling php

Comment: What operating system are you using? you might be able to find a repository with a pre-compiled version that was built with the `--enable-bcmath` flag. then you'd just need to add the repo and invoke `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: i am using centos . also beside this error why can't i access ldr function

Comment: Which version of Centos are you using? Did you manage to enable bcmath? what exception do you get when trying to invoke `ldr()` ? The one in the question or a different one ?

Comment: i am using centos6.4 . error i get is Function `ldr` is undefined in current namespace. actually i don't want to recompile php so i left that bc math. i end up using `Kint`

Comment: I just checked the ladybug code ... You're definitely not using the **latest version** of ladybug! There is no class `FloatType` anymore since the classes have been refactored **[2 months ago](https://github.com/raulfraile/ladybug/commit/cd8af24bb49752693e09cac32000b2f1cae8f56c)**. Please include your **composer.json** in the question. You probably just installed an outdated, non-working copy of the library!

Comment: i used this `"raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "~1.0"` as mentioned in the site https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle